# Constraint Flow layout rows are getting overlapped

Tags: android, android-layout, constraints, android-constraintlayout, flowlayout

**ConstraintLayout version**: 2.0.0-beta3

In Constraint flow Layout added views.Placed Views with match constraint, if the view height is wrap content and content height increases rows are overlapping. Here I added my code snippet

**Steps:**

1.Created Flow Layout

2.Created Views with width as match constraint and height as wrap content

3.flow_wrapMode="chain"

4.if I add more content to views, rows are overlapping

**Code Shippet:**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
            android:id="@+id/flow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="button2,button3,button4,button5,button6,button7"
            app:flow_maxElementsWrap="3"
            app:flow_wrapMode="chain"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"></androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button1 Button2 Button2 Button2 Button2 Button2 Button2"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
            android:text="Button2 Button1 Button2 Button2 Button2 Button2 Button2 Button2 Button1 Button2 Button2 Button2 Button2 Button2 Button2"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:text="Button3"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:text="Button 1 Button 2 Button 2 Button2 Button2 Button2 Button2 ton2 Button2 Button2 Button2 Button2 Button2 Button1 Button2 Button2 Button2 Button2 Button2 Button2"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
            android:text="Button2 ton2 Button2 Button2 Button2 Button2 Button2 Button1 Button2 Button2 Button2 Button2 Button2 Button2 ton2 Button2 Button2 Button2 Button2 Button2 Button1 Button2 Button2 Button2 Button2 Button2 Button2"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
            android:text="Button3 Button1 Button2 Button2 Button2 Button2 Button2 Button2 Button1 Button2 Button2 Button2 Button2 Button2 Button2 Button1 Button2 Button2 Button2 Button2 Button2 Button2"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144668321